# Java: Start Thread (Alternative to starting in constructor)

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there an alternative way to start a thread when an object is made (when the constructer is called). I know you can't  start the thread in a constructor. But what if I have two methods in the class (class is called Tasks) which implements Runnable: run(), continuousRecv(). The run() method calls the continuousRecv() function. The continuousRecv() does some stuff. Then I create a private class within the public class Tasks called startContRecv() and in the constructor function call start the thread, like so

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Tasks());
t1.start();
```

My code:

```
import java.lang.Runnable;

public class Tasks implements Runnable {
    public Tasks() {
        startContinousReceive conRecv = new startContinousReceive();
    }

    public void continuiousReceive() {
        while (true) {
            //Code to executed
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        continuiousReceive();
    }

    //PRIVATE CLASS WHICH STARTS THREAD
    //INSTANCE OF PRIVATE CLASS IS MADE IN CONSTRUCTOR OF TASKS CLASS

    private class startContinousReceive {
        public startContinousReceive() {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Tasks());
            t1.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get an infinite loop of instantiating Tasks objects which will end-up in an OutOfMemoryError for sure. You instantiate object1 of Tasks which in turns instantiate your private class which again instantiate another object2 of Tasks and the cycle starts over.

Comment: Do you know a way to successfully start a thread then within the class? And btw the infinite loop doesn't do any memory consuming tasks, e.g

Comment: public void continiousRecieve() {
  while (true) {
   String recv = sock.receivePacket();
   if (recv != null) {
    internalRoomID = Integer.parseInt(recv.split("%")[3]);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: you missed my point, you enter in an infinite loop of creating Tasks objects. That, for sure, affects the memory at some point :).

Comment: by calling the constructor of Tasks from your private class constructor, it will again call your private class constructor which will call again the Tasks constructor. If I think this better, it will never end the object construction, I think you will get a StackOverflow quicker :)

Comment: I dont understand, can you show me demo code please

Comment: to create the Tasks object you will have new Task() somewhere in your application and what would happened is that it would call the Thread t1 = new Thread(new Tasks()); ultimately when the inner class object is created..and hence it will try to create the object of Task again and this whole sequence gets repeated..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you want: when creating a task also start a thread with it is to define a factory method in Tasks class, and make the Tasks constructor private. See below:

```
public static void createTask( ) {
    Tasks t = new tTasks();
    Thread t  = new Thread( t) ;
    t.start( );
}
```

And declare your constructor private, in order to make sure that the only way Tasks is instantiated, is through this factory method. Otherwise you will not get also a Thread started.
Also, you should drop your inner private class, is useless in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

### Why?

It is an **antipattern** to do a lot of work in the constructor.

In particular, it breaks your ability to subclass the constructor.

So don't try to start the thread in the constructor!

Why is code like

```
new MyThread().start();
```

bad? It is very readable: make a new Thread and run it.

If you want, you can still wrap this in a method:

```
public void startNewThread() {
  new MyThread().start();
}
```